# ¿Cómo puedo renombrar una ventana con OpenCV2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Tengo un programa que lanza una nueva ventana cuando pulso un botón, dentro de esa ventana hago ciertos dibujos que se quedan plasmados en la ventana mostrada.

Lo que me gustaría conseguir es que cada vez que se hace un nuevo dibujo cambie el nombre de la ventana de "Image" a "Image*", para cuando se guarden los cambios vuelva a ser "Image".

Una de las opciones es destruir la ventana y abrir una nueva, pero es un movimiento brusco visualmente hablando (cierre de la ventana y apertura de otra nueva), y quiero que el cambio sea tan sencillo como que se actualice el nombre de la ventana simplemente.

Primero creo la ventana sobre la que coloco el handler para el callback del ratón (winname = "Image"):

```
cv2.namedWindow (winname, flags=cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.setMouseCallback (winname, mouse_crop)
```

sobre esa ventana, imprimo las imágenes que sean según las circunstancias con cv2.imshow

```
rect_cpy = image.copy()
cv2.imshow(winname, rect_cp)
```

Lo apropiado sería cambiar el nombre de esa ventana sobre la que coloco el handler y las imágenes, sin tener que destruirla.

De la siguiente manera como es lógico, no me renombra la imagen, me crea una nueva:

```
elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPt.append((x, y))
        xfin = x
        yfin = y
        cropping = False
        winname = "image*"
        cv2.imshow(winname, image)
```

¿Hay alguna función para el renombrado o a alguien se le ocurre como poder conseguirlo?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Para cambiar el nombre de la ventana, debería bastar con lo siguiente: cv2.setWindowTitle("Nombre de tu ventana", "Nuevo título")

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido!

Comment: Hola Rodnarok si la respuesta de @RodrigoN te ha solucionado la duda estaría bien que la cierres dándole al "visto" verde que tiene debajo de su puntuación. Así otras personas con la misma duda sabrán que esa es una buena respuesta y además a él le recompensas su aportación. Un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Rodnarok, a falta del código mínimo funcional, te muestro el siguiente ejemplo del uso de **setWindowTitle**:

```
import cv2
from time import sleep

nombre_ventana = "Nombre UNO"

cv2.namedWindow (nombre_ventana, flags=cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
sleep(2)
cv2.setWindowTitle(nombre_ventana, "Nombre DOS")
```

> El **sleep(2)** es sólo para que se alcance a notar cuando cambia el nombre de la ventana.

Comment: Gracias! es justamente eso lo que buscaba, el sleep lo hace mas suave incluso el cambio. 

Sólo concretar que los cambios de nombre consecutivos serán de la siguiente forma:

cv2.setWindowTitle(nombre_ventana, "Nombre DOS")
.
.
.
cv2.setWindowTitle(nombre_ventana, "Nombre TRES")

Vaya, que el primer argumento de setWindowTitle no cambia según vas cambiando el nombre varias veces, sólo hay que establecer el que quieres que tenga en el segundo argumento.